# How do I configure the launcher to “dodge windows”?

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

How do I configure the launcher to “dodge windows” in 13.04?
By unity revamped / like, please not batch files. I want to go into ccsm and enable it like in 11.10 or 12.04 with unity revamped. I don't want a batch file, because the batch file based implementations of the unity "dodge windows" are buggy.

*To clarify, dodge windows is where the launcher slides away when a window overlaps it*

Comment: A version deference is not enough to make it not a duplicate. If The other question does not have a answer for 13.04 put a bounty on it with the "Current Answers are outdated" to get a answer for the new version.

Comment: I can't give a bounty because i need at least 400 bounty and I have 298 and I am saving up for 350 so I can make tags.

Comment: I would re-code it if I knew where is the code for the dock settings.

Comment: @Andrew - this is the same question as now in the link in your question.  You'll have to wait until some enterprising developer takes "unity revamped" and makes it 13.04 compatible.

Comment: @fossfreedom I would but I have no Idea how the code work do you? I think I ask it on here how does the unity code work or something like it and no one replayed to it. I know how to program in c++, C#, Basic and few other web language. I just need someone to explain to me how to code work and what does each file do. Than I would know how.  Would you be that kind to help me I see you have some packages on your Launchpad account? ;)

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is perhaps not the best place to ask in depth questions about in-depth code related questions.  My recommendation would be to send a message to the unity revamped author and/or ask on ubuntu devs mailing list or IRC.

Comment: @fossfreedom The  unity revamped author doesn't have has e-mail publicly accessable through his  Launchpad account. IS there any other way to message him?

Comment: the original maintainer has a contact-us and is on IRC (https://launchpad.net/~ikarosdev) - the new maintainer has a contact-us link (https://launchpad.net/~garhuy)

Comment: @fossfreedom but, I do I concent him?

Comment: @Andrew - pop into the general chat room - myself or others can discuss this further.

Comment: Okay I did what time are you on?  Please tell me in CDT Time. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Time_Zone_(North_America))